# Merge two war files gradle and eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, multi-project

Below is my gradle mutli project structure

```
Root project 'suite'
+--- Project ':common-services-auth'
+--- Project ':common-services-data'
+--- Project ':common-services-rest'
\--- Project ':common-services-web'
```

Here, data is simple data service, which can be consumed by rest project or web project. auth, rest and web all are war file projects. 
I am trying to merge all war files into single war files, in maven I was able to do with overlay plugin, but couldn't find any similar plugin for gradle. I am using eclipse neon as ide.
Please can you suggest me how can I merge these 3 war files to one single war file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the `gradle-waroverlay-plugin`.

https://bintray.com/scalding/maven/gradle-waroverlay-plugin#read